# Single kafka consumer-group for many topics doesn't work with ACL

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, acl

I have the following problem:
My application subscribe on many topics (about 16-20) with single constant consumer group.

If i use kafka without SSL and ACLs - it perfectly works.

But on kafka with ssl and strictly separated ACLs i have problems.
If much part of topics are not permitted for client, then correctly topics(allowed by ACL) does not reading, consumer doesn't sends fetch requests and no one partition assigned to this.

```
2020-11-13 16:18:30.209 [INFO ] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Successfully joined group PPRBODCommandConsumer with generation 74

2020-11-13 16:18:30.209 [INFO ] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Setting newly assigned partitions [] for group PPRBODCommandConsumer

2020-11-13 16:20:54.449 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator ] [T:PRBODCommandConsumer] - Sending Heartbeat request for group PPRBODCommandConsumer to coordinator vck4-s012-kfk010.vm.mos.cloud.sbrf.ru:9093 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2020-11-13 16:20:54.452 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Received successful Heartbeat response for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:20:54.741 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:20:54.762 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:20:55.741 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:20:55.763 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:20:56.741 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:20:56.764 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:20:57.449 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator ] [T:PRBODCommandConsumer] - Sending Heartbeat request for group PPRBODCommandConsumer to coordinator vck4-s012-kfk010.vm.mos.cloud.sbrf.ru:9093 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2020-11-13 16:20:57.453 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Received successful Heartbeat response for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:20:57.742 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:20:57.765 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:20:58.743 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:20:58.766 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:20:59.744 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:20:59.767 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:00.449 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator ] [T:PRBODCommandConsumer] - Sending Heartbeat request for group PPRBODCommandConsumer to coordinator vck4-s012-kfk010.vm.mos.cloud.sbrf.ru:9093 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2020-11-13 16:21:00.453 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Received successful Heartbeat response for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:00.745 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:00.768 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:01.746 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:01.769 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:02.746 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:02.770 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:03.449 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator ] [T:PRBODCommandConsumer] - Sending Heartbeat request for group PPRBODCommandConsumer to coordinator vck4-s012-kfk010.vm.mos.cloud.sbrf.ru:9093 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2020-11-13 16:21:03.454 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Received successful Heartbeat response for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:03.747 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:03.771 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:04.748 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:04.771 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:05.749 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:05.772 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:06.450 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator ] [T:PRBODCommandConsumer] - Sending Heartbeat request for group PPRBODCommandConsumer to coordinator vck4-s012-kfk010.vm.mos.cloud.sbrf.ru:9093 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2020-11-13 16:21:06.455 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Received successful Heartbeat response for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:06.749 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:06.773 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:07.750 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:07.774 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:08.750 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:08.775 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:09.451 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator ] [T:PRBODCommandConsumer] - Sending Heartbeat request for group PPRBODCommandConsumer to coordinator vck4-s012-kfk010.vm.mos.cloud.sbrf.ru:9093 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2020-11-13 16:21:09.455 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Received successful Heartbeat response for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:09.751 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:09.776 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:10.752 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:10.777 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:11.753 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
2020-11-13 16:21:11.778 [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator ] [T:main                ] - Completed auto-commit of offsets {} for group PPRBODCommandConsumer
```

When i produce in it topics - messages are not read by consumer.

But if all topics permitted for client or if i use individual consumer group for each topic - it perfectly work

Is this a known Kafka bug?
Or Kafka not designed to be used with single consumer group for many topics?